# woocommerce_update_product action – fire only once for every product update

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Which workaround is there for making the woocommerce_update_product action fire only once?

I've read that it fires twice because it needs to save once internally to retrieve an ID for images/variation saves.

But from a developer experience, this is really not what most need, I guess.

The only workaround I've found so far is to add the action and remove it in the hook directly:

```
add_action('woocommerce_update_product', 'my_product_update', 10, 2);
function my_product_update($product_id, $product){
    remove_action('woocommerce_update_product');
    // We'll get here only once!
}
```

However, this breaks when trying to do bulk edits, making it so that the hook only fires for the first product (because it gets removed afterwards!).

Which other way is there to work around this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: how about add custom meta in updated products? after update all products remove it.

Comment: How would I know when to remove the custom meta data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe using [WordPress Transient](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/transients/) can help.

```
add_action('woocommerce_update_product', 'my_product_update', 10, 2);
function my_product_update($product_id, $product) {

    $updating_product_id = 'update_product_' . $product_id;
    if ( false === ( $updating_product = get_transient( $updating_product_id ) ) ) {
        // We'll get here only once! within 2 seconds for each product id;
        // run your code here!
        set_transient( $updating_product_id , $product_id, 2 ); // change 2 seconds if not enough
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only thing I'm worrying about is actual updates coming in faster than the specified time.

Comment: would that actually happen? like updating a single product more than once in 2 seconds? it can but I don't think it would practically.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. In there it could, but it's probably unlikely (and may be worth ignoring). Thanks for bringing that up!

Comment: you can even set it to 1 second... It should work if you put `set_transient` at the very last line to run... like how it is right now...

Comment: Yep, I did that. One more question about the code: why does the if-statement not just say: if (!get_transient($updating_product))? For me that seems to work fine.

Comment: depending on use. I have edited my answer to make it more clear. but yes, your `if` should work too...

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: This really helped me send push notifications about Product adds and updates using Firebase Cloud Messaging to a Flutter application because `woocommerce_update_product` hook runs twice and two notifications were being sent.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [global variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) to do this in memory, no database entry required:

```
add_action('woocommerce_update_product', 'my_product_update', 10, 2);
function my_product_update($product_id, $product){
    global $previous_product_id;
    if ($previous_product_id === $product_id){
        // We'll get here only once (per product)!
    }
    $previous_product_id = $product_id;
}
```

Comment: This seems sweetest of the answers :)

Answer (score 1):

i ran into the same issue (actually my hook was firing 5 times). I found a solution on the following [page](https://www.forumming.com/question/21114/unable-to-prevent-function-using-save-post-firing-twice) in the last comment.

Namely, the use of:

```php
$times = did_action('woocommerce_update_product');
if( $times === 1){
    //  Do some stuff
}
```

Comment: What if someone updates multiple products in one request? This method does not check for product ID, so it will be only called once for all products, instead of once per product

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution would be to set a `$_POST` variable and check at the start of the function.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'my_action', 10, 1 );
function my_action(){
   if( isset($_POST['action_performed']) ){
      //Prevent running the action twice
      return;
    }
   
   // do you stuff here

   $_POST['action_performed'] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy and fast solution is the use of the debug_backtrace() php function. The first time that is triggered uses `debug_backtrace()[8]['class'] === "WC_Meta_Box_Product_Data"`. The second time uses `(debug_backtrace()[8]['class'] === "WC_Meta_Box_Product_Images"`.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'ml_update_product'));

public function ml_update_product($product_id)
{
    if(debug_backtrace()[8]['class'] === "WC_Meta_Box_Product_Images"){
    // Your code firing once
    }
}
```

Maybe not the best solution because it can change in the future with an Woocommerce update but for sure is the fastest and easiest solution.