# Custom code is not working after updating the woocommerce 5.5 to 6

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I created the custom code for punching the stock value (only for variable & simple product).This custom code will work/punch when the new product added in woocommerce via admin dashboard .For this i am using the the action hook called -

> added_post_meta

My custom code for reading the stock value is

```
function wc_set_product_stock_callback_post_meta_new($meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value )
{
    global $wpdb;
    global $current_user;
    global $post;   

    if(get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'product' && get_post_status( $post_id ) == 'publish')
        {
            $product_id = $post_id;
            $tablename = $wpdb->prefix.'woocommerce_stock_master';
            if(!$product_id)
            {
                return;
            }  

            wp_get_current_user();
            $user_id = $current_user->ID;

            // get an instance of the WC_Product Object
            $product    = wc_get_product( $product_id );

            $current_product_id = $product->get_id(); 
            $stock_qty  = $product->get_stock_quantity();
            $stock_notes = 'New Stock';
            $producut_in_master = check_stock_in_master($current_product_id);
            $is_stock = get_post_meta( $current_product_id , '_stock',true);
            $product_type = $product->get_type();
            $manage_stock = get_post_meta( $current_product_id , '_manage_stock',true);
           
           if ($product->is_type( 'variable' )){
                 //$product_id = $product->get_id(); 
                 $manage_stock_var = get_post_meta( $current_product_id , '_manage_stock',true);

                 if($manage_stock_var == 'yes')
                 {
                    $current_stk = $stock_qty;         
                    if(empty($current_stk))//Stock Value Check - Product Added But with No/Empty Stock Value
                    {
                        $stock_notes = 'New Stock with 0 Qty';
                    }      
                    $wpdb->insert( $tablename, array( 'post_ID' =>  $current_product_id, 'user_ID' => $user_id, 'stock_quantity'=>  $current_stk ,'notes'=> $stock_notes,'product_type' =>$product_type ) );
                 }
                $variations = $product->get_children(); // get variations
                foreach ($variations as $variations_value) {
                    $single_variation = new WC_Product_Variation($variations_value);
                    $single_variation_stock = $single_variation->get_stock_quantity();
                    $variation_producut_in_master = check_stock_in_master($variations_value);
                    $manage_stock_variation = get_post_meta( $variations_value , '_manage_stock',true);
                    if($variation_producut_in_master <= 0 && $manage_stock_variation == 'yes')
                    {
                        $variation_current_stk = $single_variation_stock;
                        if(empty($variation_current_stk))//Stock Value Check - Variation Product Added But with No/Empty Stock Value
                        {
                        $stock_notes = 'New variation Stock with 0 Qty';
                        } 
                        $wpdb->insert( $tablename, array( 'post_ID' => $variations_value, 'user_ID' => $user_id, 'stock_quantity'=>  $variation_current_stk ,'notes'=> $stock_notes,'product_type' =>$product_type,'variation_of' => $current_product_id) );
                    }
                }
           }
           if ($product->is_type( 'simple' )){
                if($producut_in_master <= 0 && $manage_stock == 'yes')
                {
                    if($is_stock !='')
                    {
                        $simple_current_stk = $stock_qty;
                        if($simple_current_stk == 0)//Stock Value Check - Product Added But with No/Empty Stock Value
                        {
                            $stock_notes = 'New Stock with 0 Qty';
                        }   
                        $wpdb->insert( $tablename, array( 'post_ID' =>  $current_product_id, 'user_ID' => $user_id, 'stock_quantity'=>  $simple_current_stk ,'notes'=> $stock_notes,'product_type' =>$product_type) );
                    }    
                }
            }
        }else{
            return;
        }
        error_log('Quantity is '.$stock_qty . "--".$producut_in_master );   
  
       
}
```

And calling the call back function like this -

> add_action( 'added_post_meta','wc_set_product_stock_callback_post_meta_new',10,4);

**Custom table SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_custom_woocommerce_stock_master` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `stock_quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adjust_stock` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `notes` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `product_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `variation_of` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Custom function code**

```
function check_stock_in_master($post_ID)
{
/* This function will read the value from wp_woocommerce_stock_master according to post ID 
    And reurn an $rowcount
 */
    global $post;
    global $wpdb;
    $current_post = $post_ID;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_woocommerce_stock_master WHERE post_id =  $current_post");
    $rowcount = $wpdb->num_rows;
    return $rowcount;
}
```

My this implementation was working fine with WP-5.8.2 & WC 5.5.2. But after updating the wooCommerce 6 same code for variable product is not working. After debugging the code i found that, in woocommerce 6  the following if block is not working as expected.

> if(get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'product' && get_post_status( $post_id ) == 'publish')

Is there any difference in internal working of WC5.5 & WC6.0. OR i was using the wrong hook for punching/reading the stock values.Or is there any other way for reading the value of stock when the new product added.

**UPDATE on 13-01-22**

I tried the action hook *woocommerce_update_product* suggested in https://www.mootpoint.org/blog/woocommerce-hook-product-updated-added/

After replacing the hook, code is working but it seems this hook  woocommerce_update_product runs twice.Due to this i am getting two row for each new product inserted. Why it is running twice.

Any one please advice on this.

Comment: See [WooCommerce hook on product updated or added](https://www.mootpoint.org/blog/woocommerce-hook-product-updated-added/) -> updated method for WooCommerce 3.x.. AND [Update product stock quantity and status in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64546874/11987538). Since your code uses a custom table [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is missing. Therefore I limit myself to this comment compared to answering your question.

Comment: Thanks 7uc1f3r for reply. Sorry for Minimal reproducible issue. I added my custom table sql & function in question.

Comment: @7uc1f3r Thanks for suggesting the link.I tried the action hook woocommerce_update_product suggested in link. After replacing the hook, code is working but it seems this hook  woocommerce_update_product runs twice.Due to this i am getting two row for each new product inserted. Why it is running twice. 
Can you please guide me on this.

Comment: see [woocommerce_update_product action – fire only once for every product update](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59527908/11987538)